# Amazon EMR: Set unique number of mappers and reducers per EMR instance

Tags: hadoop, configuration, mapreduce, amazon-emr

I'm running an Amazon EMR cluster that has M core instances and N task instances.

My jobs run multiple times per day and are time sensitive so I am keeping the M core instances up and running 24/7 so that I don't have data transfer overhead to/from S3.

The N task nodes are being dynamically launched and terminated as needed.

The M core nodes are c1.mediums and the N task nodes are m2.xlarge.

Is there a way to configure mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum and mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum per instance?

For the core nodes I want:
mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=2
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=1

For the task nodes I want at least:
mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum=2
mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum=2

Note that task trackers run on the core nodes as well, so I think this configuration will need to be on a per-instance basis depending on the instance size.

Is this possible? And if so how can I set up this type of configuration?

Answer (score -1):

There is a great blog here - which gives you the answer.
http://blog.earlh.com/index.php/2013/05/modifying-the-number-of-mappers-or-reducers-on-a-running-emr-cluster/

Note though that you might have to play around a bit with sshing into your task nodes. It will not work just like that.

I would get my pem file onto a local directory.

chmod 400 on that pem file

and then do "scp -l hadoop -i .pem  and then the rest of of it"

as mentioned in the blog
Mind you I have not tried this yet but I believe it will work.
Also - the .versions... stuff may not be needed. You will probably just need conf.

Thanks

Comment: Link is dead :-(